# Flyway repeatable migrations runs randomly

Tags: flyway

I use Flyway-core 5.1.4 version in my Java Spring boot project.
I know if I change something in R_ migraion I will get new record in flyway_schema_history table with new checksum. But I got random apply of repeatable migrations in the end of my flyway_schema_history table without any changes in R- migration, even without additing any V_ migrations and without re compiling or redeploying of my project.
How is it possible ? 
And it seems to me that I got old version of my R- migration, something like overriding.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the checksum of the repeatable migration change each time it is run? You should do, as that's the trigger for it to be re-run; and if that is happening then it suggests something is changing the file, perhaps only whitespace but that is enough.

Comment: Thank you @Julia Hayward, for answer. Of course I understand if checksum changed it means changing in R_ migration file. But it could happened only if I (rerun application), restart Tomcat for example. Am I right ?

Comment: I mean appling possible only after application restarting.